# How to expand wrapper when content is more?(with CSS)

Tags: html, css

I use following style sheet:

```
html, body 
{
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper 
{
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fffcfc;
  width: 840px;
  padding:5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px  #888888;
}
.content
{
  width:670px;
  float:right;
  padding:5px;
  border:solid 1px;
}
.left
{
  width:160px;
  float:left;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.footer
{
  height: 40px;
  background:#33559b;
  text-align:center;
  color: #ebe4e4;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:10pt;
  margin-top:10px;
 clear: both;
}
```

Problem is when records in content is more , content is expand but wrapper not expand and it has fixed height. How to expand wrapper when content is more?

Output:

[image]

Comment: You may need to share the HTML markup ... I guess you aren't clearing the `float` of the content

Comment: Something like this? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/nwX85/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this **CSS** in your stylesheet:

```
.clear { clear: both; }
```

Then put a clear div just before the closing tag of your wrapper `div`.

```
<div class="wrapper">
 Your content
 <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There was never a genius like @Era

Comment: Lol, hey @NoobEditor... I beat your rep yesterday, by 1! HA! :D

Comment: @Ruddy : lol....my target was 20 days on SO, 4 more days... and i think i did pretty well in that...now you have all the time to beat me...cheers!! :D